# Rails 4: Use Operators within Loops

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, controller, operators

I am struggling with checking the param `user_id`. How can I change that from `=>` to something similar this operator: `!=`

And fortunately how can I do the same with `<=` and `>=`

```
- @jobsforyou.where(:is_finished => false, :is_active => true, :user_id => current_user, :sort <= 2).limit(10).each do |job|
```

*The code-example gives an error.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For not you can directly do this

```
@jobsforyou.where.not(user_id: current_user)
```

For `<=` and `>=` you can use something similar to this

```
@jobsforyou.where("sort < ?", 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

`=>` in your example is not *equal or bigger than*. It is the syntax of a hash. To write more complex queries you will need to use another syntax - for example the pure string syntax:

```
@jobsforyou.where(:is_finished => false, :is_active => true, :user_id => current_user
           .where('sort <= 2')
           .limit(10)
```

Read more about how to build [queries in Ruby on Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#conditions) in the Rails Guides.